What is the meaning of "it insists upon itself" when referring the movie The Godfather?
In the TV show Family Guy, the character Peter says that he is not partial to the movie Godfather, and he says the reason is that the movie "insists upon itself".
What does that mean?
Video link and relevant scene:


The point of the comment rather than the literal meaning is they're drowning and he's critiquing films. Drowning is serious as the water insists upon itself, and he's sharing secrets of the heart...about movies that are taken with their own importance.

You should try a dictionary before posting here. The definition of insist will definitely give some of it, although don't try to read too much into what Peter says. It's probably intended as a copy or mistaken reproduction of the language of film critics.

It's a joke. A thing cannot insist upon itself. Only a person can...

It doesn't mean anything -- that's the point of Lois's response "What does that even mean?". It just sounds like something a pretentious film critic would say.
The closest thing to an actual meaning might be that the director tried too hard to make it seem important, but didn't succeed. Kind of like a narcisistic person who is "full of himself."

So it's a pretentious condemnation of pretense.

The other users are mentioning the use of the phrase in the context of The Family Guy to tell a joke. These answers are correct.
But "it insists upon itself" does have meaning beyond the joke.
It's essentially a way of saying "look at me", that the film is self-absorbed and self-conscious, that it doesn't really acknowledge any kind of lightness or irony, or any sense that it's mere entertainment, or any acceptance that it may be flawed; that it's pompous, self-important and relentless.
The way this construction works is that were someone to say "but it's only a bit of fun" the film would say "no I'm the best", it would insist on how wonderful it is, on itself, just like a pretentious person.
The reason this construction has been chosen is that it's in a register used by hack critics. For example it uses a form which is grammatically precise but semantically awkward and ambiguous, requiring work on the part of the reader. The intention is to demonstrate the apparent intelligence of the writer. (Apparent at least to the writer!)
